# Can we use DAOs directly in controller instead of business layer objects?

Tags: design-patterns, dao, business-logic, service-layer, business-logic-layer

I am not just getting one thing.. I am working on some internal project.. (java/spring/hibernate).  Iam using dao layer, presentaion layer.. Is that necessary to use Business layer in my app?

The reason i asked because, whatever the methods are there in dao's, the same methods exists in business layer too.. so I can directly use DAOs into my controller instead of Business layer objects..

Please correct me if iam wrong.. iam not much experienced in writing code on big applications.. so pls advice me (if possible any example pls)

and what you say service layer? do you think I need this for a small application like mine? (I guess we use service layer only when we use webservices, right?)

Waiting for your replies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I really need a service layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633498/do-i-really-need-a-service-layer)

Comment: @JBNizet BUT Iam asking about Business layer too.. could u pls tell if u knew about it..?

Comment: Business layer and service layer are the same thing. Synonyms.

Comment: @JBNizet I dont think they're same.. I heard service layer will built on top of business layer

Comment: please need some more replies for my query..

Comment: Some people call service and business layer the same thing...they really are not. One contains the business rules, the other is a façade over the business logic that exposes the logic to remote clients over the network.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a business layer in all but the most simplest throw-away applications. I would go as far to say that separation of presentation from the business logic is more important than separation of the business logic from the data access (though you should really have both).

Often it seems like a business layer is not necessary when an application does little more than CRUD. This falls over, however, when:

1. You need to change the UI framework for your application...and UI technology evolves quickly
2. You need to expose your business logic to different client code as a library or to remove clients via web services
3. Your application grows...and acquires more serious business rules
4. You want to start unit testing your business logic

If you place business logic into your presentation layer/controllers then your business logic will forever be tied to your presentation layer. You are basically placing an artificial life expiry over the code that you are writing and limiting its re-usability at the same time. When you need to change the UI technology, you will need to write your business logic again.

There are a lot of VB6 applications that have had to be abandoned and rewritten for this reason:  they should have written their business logic in C++ COM objects...they can be called from .NET. These same VB6 programmers went on to VB.NET Winforms and have made the same mistake over again.

EDIT: As for services: Write the service layer WHEN it is needed. The service layer is usually a thin layer that sits in front of the business layer. It is actually a client of your business logic. Often it will have the same Interfaces. You don't need one unless you need to expose your logic over a network. I have worked on teams that have insisted on writing WCF layers in front of their business logic...only to then run all of the code on the same machine anyway. Waste of time and slows the application down.