# Using JTA transaction in JAX-RS ContainerResponseFilter, any side effects?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jta, transactional

I have a provider where I can always read Entities but I was never write some until I set the `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` on class level and the `@Transactional` on the overridden filter method.

```
@Provider
@Priority(value = 1)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class SecurityUsageResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyAppPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {
        //code

        updateUserAndHeaderInformation(id, responseContext);

        //code
    }

    private void updateUserAndHeaderInformation(Object userId, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
    {
        //This ALWAYS work
        RestrictedUsers user = entityManager.find(RestrictedUsers.class, userId);

        //Only works when transactions are explicitly set
        user.setLastTransferToken(newTransferToken);
        user.setLastObfuscationId(newObfuscationId);
    }
}
```

My question is: Are there maybe any side effects when the `filter` method is suddenly transactional? Usually transactions are only used in service methods, but here I'm using a provider any maybe there is some different behaviour in the background which could interfere things I didn't think about yet?

Comment: It may work but why don't you keep your filter lean and delegate these operations to a service layer?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I already thought about that. I think it's indeed a better style. I extracted the important parts to a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work but I wouldn't do that.

Your filter should be kept *lean* and these operations should be *delegated* to the service layer, which is responsible for [demarcating the transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633643/1426227).